# How can BLAS library be directly used with boost multiarrays?

Tags: c++11, boost, matrix-multiplication

Given two matrices `A` and `B`, and `C` for the result of their multiplication.

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> matrix;
int m=5;
int n=6;
int k=7;

matrix A(boost::extents[m][k]);
matrix B(boost::extents[k][n]);
matrix C(boost::extents[m][n]);
```

How can `dgemm` function from the `blas` library be called to compute matrix product of `A` and `B`?
I am aware of the `uBLAS` part `boost` library, `armadillo`, `MTL 4`, `eigen` and some other libraries that provide convenient wrappers for `blas` functions. The question here is how to *directly* call `dgemm` on the multi-arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the contiguous element storage.

The prototype is

> `void cblas_dgemm( CBLAS_LAYOUT layout, CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransA, CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransB, const int M, const int N, const int K, const double alpha, const double *A, const int lda, const double *B, const int ldb, const double beta, double *C, const int ldc )`

So, let's fill it in:

```
cblas_dgemm(
    CBLAS_LAYOUT::CblasRowMajor,
    CBLAS_TRANSPOSE::CblasNoTrans,
    CBLAS_TRANSPOSE::CblasNoTrans,
    m, n, k,
    1.0, // alpha
    A.data(), A.shape()[1],
    B.data(), B.shape()[1],
    0.0, // beta
    C.data(), C.shape()[1]);
```

> That was using the [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1513282-cblas_dgemm?language=objc) for a bit of guidance on alpha/beta: [image]

### Demo

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> matrix;

#include <iostream>
namespace io { // for debug output
    auto& dump(std::ostream& os, double v) { return os << v; }

    template <typename R> auto& dump(std::ostream& os, R const& r) {
        std::string_view sep = "";
        os << "{";
        for (auto const& el : r) { dump(os << sep, el); sep = ","; }
        return os << "}";
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, matrix const& m) { return io::dump(os, m); }

// demo
#include <cblas-netlib.h>
#include <numeric> // iota

int main() {
    constexpr auto m=5, n=6, k=7;

    matrix A(boost::extents[m][k]);
    matrix B(boost::extents[k][n]);
    matrix C(boost::extents[m][n]);

    std::iota(A.data(), A.data() + A.num_elements(), 0);
    std::iota(B.data(), B.data() + B.num_elements(), 50);
    std::iota(C.data(), C.data() + C.num_elements(), 100);

    std::cout << "A: " << A << "\nB: " << B << "\n";
    assert(A.storage_order().all_dims_ascending());

    /*
     * void cblas_dgemm(
     *   CBLAS_LAYOUT layout,
     *   CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransA,
     *   CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransB,
     *   const int M, const int N, const int K,
     *   const double alpha,
     *   const double *A, const int lda,
     *   const double *B, const int ldb,
     *   const double beta,
     *   double *C, const int ldc )
     */

    cblas_dgemm(
        CBLAS_LAYOUT::CblasRowMajor,
        CBLAS_TRANSPOSE::CblasNoTrans,
        CBLAS_TRANSPOSE::CblasNoTrans,
        m, n, k,
        1.0, // alpha
        A.data(), A.shape()[1],
        B.data(), B.shape()[1],
        0.0, // beta
        C.data(), C.shape()[1]);

    std::cout << "C:\n" << C << "\n";
}
```

Which prints:

```
A: {{0,1,2,3,4,5,6},{7,8,9,10,11,12,13},{14,15,16,17,18,19,20},{21,22,23,24,25,26,27},{28,29,30,31,32,33,34}}
B: {{50,51,52,53,54,55},{56,57,58,59,60,61},{62,63,64,65,66,67},{68,69,70,71,72,73},{74,75,76,77,78,79},{80,81,82,83,84,85},{86,87,88,89,90,91}}
C:
{{1596,1617,1638,1659,1680,1701},{4928,4998,5068,5138,5208,5278},{8260,8379,8498,8617,8736,8855},{11592,11760,11928,12096,12264,12432},{14924,15141,15358,15575,15792,16009}}
```

This checks out with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrix+multiplication+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22MatricesOperations%22%2C+%22theMatrix2%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B50%2C51%2C52%2C53%2C54%2C55%7D%2C%7B56%2C57%2C58%2C59%2C60%2C61%7D%2C%7B62%2C63%2C64%2C65%2C66%2C67%7D%2C%7B68%2C69%2C70%2C71%2C72%2C73%7D%2C%7B74%2C75%2C76%2C77%2C78%2C79%7D%2C%7B80%2C81%2C82%2C83%2C84%2C85%7D%2C%7B86%2C87%2C88%2C89%2C90%2C91%7D%7D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22MatricesOperations%22%2C+%22theMatrix1%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%7D%2C%7B7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13%7D%2C%7B14%2C15%2C16%2C17%2C18%2C19%2C20%7D%2C%7B21%2C22%2C23%2C24%2C25%2C26%2C27%7D%2C%7B28%2C29%2C30%2C31%2C32%2C33%2C34%7D%7D%22):

[image]

Comment: Amazing, this fully solves my question and hopefully will be useful for others as well!